# What do "a low key" and "to name a few" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

-Hi there! I am a native Houstonian, moved out of state to get my college degree, but then came back. My friends would describe me as sweet, loyal, caring and slightly goofy at times ;-). My family and friends are very important to me, and I try to do what I can to maintain those relationships. My immediate family lives in the area, so I like having that support system nearby. A good chunk of my friends are married and have kids, so that limits the availability of them getting out to do things with me.

-Music is probably my biggest passion and I love going to concerts! My usual is mostly Rock/Alternative, but it can vary depending on the day and what mood I'm in. I enjoy going out to eat/drinks with friends, trying new places, photography, travelling, and going to games **to name a few**. I enjoy going out on the town for drinks or dancing, but not one that will be at the clubs every weekend. I prefer places where you can actually hear the people you're with. I am also good with just having **a low key evening at home** , and at times rather would do that. I like watching most major sports, baseball in particular. And yes, I am still an Astros fan! :-) I also enjoy playing volleyball, sand or court, and currently am playing sand volleyball on a team through work.

-I am looking to find new friends to enjoy Houston with, but ultimately I am at the stage of my life where I am ready for a real relationship. I am not interested in finding guys who want to just "hook up." I would like someone that I can feel comfortable with, who is honest, compassionate, and thoughtful. Laughter is essential in a relationship, so someone that can make me laugh is important (and not only with crude jokes/sayings).

-Feel free to send me a wink or email if you're interested or have questions to know more about me.

Does the word "goofy" is a slang meaning act like a retard person, do things without think? Having unusual habits? Which aspect of it does the slang goofy put emphasize on?

" support system nearby", I think it has two parts , part1 support system part 2 nearby. What is a support system and what kind of support system is a support system nearby? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

At first she says, **to name a few** . What does it mean, to name? And what part of speech is the word **few** ? Object or adverb?

She also use the expression **a low key evening at home** , what does she mean by that?

Comment: Think about "to name a few". (few is a noun; you could think of it as becoming a noun by virtue of remaining after elision of "few [things]".     It seems obvious she has named a few things that she enjoys. So why does she bother to say it? Because _to name a few_ is a set phrase meaning "I mentioned a few, but there are others I could have named." It's like "x,y,z, etc." but more colloquial.

Comment: As for "low key(sic), it should be  **low-key" which is a hyphenated adjective.  Writer left out the hyphen.  http://i.word.com/idictionary/low-key

Comment: @Brian, I'd add this to my answer if you'd permit. :)

Answer (score 1):

to name a few - indicative that there's an enumeration, and the enumeration is **not** exhaustive (you did not include some, you just named a few). To name (in this context - to enumerate/identify); a few (used as a substitute to an implied object, you named what? a few [of your activities/passion])

low key evening - I believe this refers to an evening filled with inactive activities (implied - staying at home AND watching TV) i.e., an inactive evening

Considering a good point from @Brian's comment, such inactivity (in context) may refer to a quiet and relaxed 'ambience'.

Answer (score 0):

[Goofy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goofy): eccentric or silly (when describing oneself as *goofy*, it's generally meant as having a slightly unusual sense of humor).

"support system nearby": her family is her "support system," and they are nearby ("lives in the area").  A [support system](http://blogs.psychcentral.com/positive-psychology/2011/06/do-you-have-a-positive-social-support-system) in this context means she has people that she can rely on for help if needed (emotionally, spiritually, etc.).

Brian and shin did a good job of answering the other two questions.